# Derby Database-Search

Tags: java, sql, extract, derby

I have linked my database to my project, have called the entity classes from the db and bound the db to a jtable. That's all well and good. But now I need to manipulate the database.

(I cannot submit any code for overview, as I do not know where to start)

What I have done so far

1. Insertion of a Item
2. Deleting of a Item
3. Updating of a Item

I now need to extract the first, second and last record of the database. I am using the .obj file to manipulate the Derby DB.

Comment: in a table in the relational database records are not stored in particular order, so there is no meaning in the `first`, `second` and `last` record in the table, unless every record has a field, that holds a particular numeric value you want to use in this context.

Comment: Rafael Osipov we can consider he has a field date that hold this timing value.

Comment: and what approach are you using in your project? Do you use SQL or are you working with binary files?

Comment: I am using a persistence unit to manipulate the DB. We cant use SQL or binary files to manipulate the DB.  There is a primary key field in the DB, that is what I hoping to extract the first second and so forth records. It is a ID field, not a date field

Comment: I am trying to get the literal first record of the DB, not a date record.

Answer (score 0):

you can have one query to perform selection of record 1,2 and last together doing so.
I have supposed you have a date field  to know the order of the records  first/last records. :D

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE <conditions>
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 2

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE <conditions>
ORDER BY date ASC    
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: While this is what is required, it is not allowed in the project criteria. If it was, I would have SQL'ed the entire thing. Unfortunately, I am forced to use a persistence unit and Entity Manager to manipulate my services DB.